# Download Blob xlsx file

Tags: excel, angular, blob, xlsx

I'm pretty new one to angular and I need to create blob xlsx file. I have tried many different ways, like changing content-type to different formats etc. but nothing helps. I get error when I try to load xlsx file through Excel. If I download directly through URL it works fine. I have no idea what's wrong.

```
t.prototype.downloadXlsx = function () {
            var t = this, e = {
                date_from: this.helpers.formatDate(this.filter.date_from),
                date_to: this.helpers.formatDate(this.filter.date_to),
                download: "fees"
            };
            this.http.get("team-accounts/" + this.route.snapshot.params.id, e).subscribe(function (n) {
                var i = {type: 'application/octet-stream'},
                    r = t.account.team.name + "_summary_" + e.date_from + "_" + e.date_to + ".xlsx";
                t.helpers.downloadXlsxFile(n._body, i, r);
            })

t.prototype.downloadXlsxFile = function (t, e, n, i) {
            var r = new Blob(t], e);
            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) navigator.msSaveBlob(r, n); else {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                if (void 0 !== a.download) {
                    var o = i || document.body, s = URL.createObjectURL(r);
                    a.setAttribute("href", s), a.setAttribute("download", n), a.style.visibility = "hidden", o.appendChild(a), a.click(), o.removeChild(a)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
t.prototype.downloadXlsx = function () {
   var t = this, e = {
        date_from: this.helpers.formatDate(this.filter.date_from),
        date_to: this.helpers.formatDate(this.filter.date_to),
        download: "fees"
   };
   this.http.get("team-accounts/" + this.route.snapshot.params.id, e).subscribe( n => {

        var url = t.account.team.name + "_summary_" + e.date_from + "_" + e.date_to + ".xlsx";

       // file download section
       const a = document.createElement('a');
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       const blob = new Blob([atob(n['_body'])], { type: 'octet/stream' });
      // if octet/stream is not working then try this one application/ms-excel
       const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       a.href = url;
       a.download = "filename.xlsx"; // you need to write the extension of file here
       a.click();
       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
```

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: hey Yash. thank you for the answer. I have tried but file is not loading. I changed
`a.download = "filename.csv";` to `filename.xlsx` but I it's just a filename and doesn't impact on the file load error I guess

Comment: Yes you are right is there any error in console and can you show me the api response? so it would help me to identify the issues bcs in my recent project i implement like this and it is working :)

Comment: There's no error in the console. 
Here's the screenshot of response:
https://i.imgur.com/wY1MUTM.png
Thank you!!

Comment: Hey @JJonas it is showing me response headers instead of response by the server

Comment: @JJonas can you please log the url and copy that url and open that url in new tab on chrome browser and let me know the result.expected result would be file needs to be downloading

Comment: @JJonas if you already have working code please write a answer so other developers getting help from your code thanks 

Comment: Hey Yash. If I open it only as URL I just file download and nothing else. The screen of website doesn't change. I don't have working code yet :( It just downloads corrupted xlsx file

Comment: URL is something like: mywebiste.com/api/web/v2/team-accounts/8?date_from=2019-03-30&date_to=2019-04-30&download=fees

Comment: Okay, So we found the issue i think there are problem with api response bcs if we open the url on new tab it will download the xlsx file so it might be issues from backend side

Comment: I'm so sorry Rami. I made mistake - if I download through URL the xlsx file works fine. But then it's through button click ( angular + blob ) file corrupt problem appears.  So the problem must be with angular

Comment: Okay but our download code does't give any error am i right?

Comment: can you change the content type in blob try this one "application/vnd.ms-excel"

const blob = new Blob([n], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });

Comment: it's a bit strange. Now then I download file and I open it, I see this: 

`Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://example.org/api/web/v2/team-accounts/8?date_from=2019-03-30&date_to=2019-04-30&download=fees`

Comment: sry i ma not getting when you open the xlsx file the data of the file is "Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://example.org/api/web/v2/team-accounts/8?date_from=2019-03-30&date_to=2019-04-30&download=fees" ????? am i right

Comment: and did you change the content type to this "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: yes, i did change to content type to "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: can you log the response in file download section?

Comment: no I mean write the console.log(n); before this
 const blob = new Blob([n], { type: 'octet/stream' });

Comment: bcs now i need to debug line by line to identify the issues

Comment: @JJonas I found the issue you xslx data is coming in _body key so we need to set that key inside blob I already update my answer pls check. let me know it is working or not 

       const blob = new Blob([n._body], { type: 'octet/stream' });

Comment: Content is loading in the file fine now. But I still get file corrupted error :(
I tried both:
                `const blob = new Blob([n._body], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });` and 
                `const blob = new Blob([n._body], { type: 'octet/stream' });`

Comment: can you show the log of this console.log(n.t._body); bcs i think _body is inside the "t" key

Comment: soo final blob is const blob = new Blob([n.t._body], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });

Comment: Response is: https://i.imgur.com/det0iWn.png

I did:                
 `console.log(n); `
 `console.log(n.t._body);`

Comment: only you need to do is get the _body from response and the pass that data to blob so after that your code is working as expected  
try this console.log(n['_body']); and let me know the result

Comment: The content is already passed to the blob file. But still file is corrupted :(
Here's file content: https://i.imgur.com/KKCO67G.png

Comment: sry brother now i dont have any idea why it is still corrupted but our file download code is working as expected now i have to debug line by line to find the issue i think there might be encryption issues 
if my answer is help you out please accept my answer thanks !!!

Comment: lets try one more thing try to decode the _body and pass that _body to blob 
console.log(atob(<your _body value>));

Comment: I tried this:                 console.log(atob(n['_body']));

And got error console:
`ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Comment: you need to use arrow function for the api call
 this.http.get("team-accounts/" + this.route.snapshot.params.id, e).subscribe(n =>  {
// our code 
}

Comment: I tried this, but file is still corrupt and error message is same.
Can you please post final function. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I changed const urlc = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); because I got `Identifier 'url' has already been declared`.
But I still get error: `ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Comment: Sorry brother now i have to debug line by line to  resolve your issue :(

Comment: Oh no problem. Thank you for trying to help that much. I appreciate your effort. Thank you Yash!

Comment: same code is not working for me, file is getting downloaded but once try to open file its showing like this .... `Excel cannot open the file filename.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`